# drivelist on Windows error (A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed) when used in an NW.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, node-gyp

I have a 0.35.4 NW.js application that needs to use drivelist in order to list available SD cards, but I keep getting the following error:

[image]

All I'm trying to do is just list all of the attached drives at the moment, but whenever I call `drivelist.list()` all I get is that error.

This is the code I am using:

```
const drivelist = require('drivelist');

listDevices();

async function listDevices() {
    let drives = await drivelist.list();
    console.log(drives);
}
```

No matter what the error pops up. I'm using the latest version of drivelist, I've installed nw-gyp, I've followed the instructions [here](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Use%20Native%20Node%20Modules/) and [here](https://nwjs.io/blog/install-native-modules-with-npm/), but no luck. I need this module to work in order for my application to function properly, can anyone help? Any ideas would be much appreciated!